# How do I make Ubuntu look like Windows 98 or XP?

Tags: themes, windows-xp

[image: a busy cat]

After Using LPS OS and feeling its very fast and simple, I got interested in transforming Ubuntu into this kind of desktop but I cannot find any article or tutorial on the Internet about it.

I would like any help like linking to tutorial or making a tutorial for me here.

Comment: Are you referring to this OS? (http://distrowatch.com/images/cgfjoewdlbc/lps.png) - Apparently it uses ICEWM for its window manager.

Comment: THe problem is if I use IceWM , All the Text will be gone very small ask you cant see them after all.

Comment: http://www.noobslab.com/2014/01/windows-xp-theme-is-available-for.html ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about LPS OS, but if you are looking for a start menu kind of thing then you can try this :

[Install cinnamon Interface on Ubuntu](http://www.howtogeek.com/103691/install-linux-mints-new-cinnamon-desktop-on-ubuntu/)

It may be what you are looking for

Comment: Thank You , I like that one but That's not what I want , You will understand what I want take a look here
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbP6dVtlU-k&feature=related

Comment: will anybody reply??

Comment: Try this : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9T-7BEJpwcI It looks like exactly waht you are loking for. First you will need to install gnome user interface to use this..

Comment: It's download link is broken : http://ubuntu.online02.com/node/14

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I managed it my own way

First I went to Gnome-Classic Desktop Session

Then I Deleted the Bottom Panel By ALT+Right Click on the panel and selecting delete this panel.

After that

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Next step download this
https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxwaHJhbmtkYWNoaWNrZW58Z3g6NTZhNTNlOTdlM2I0YTUyNQ

and follow this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4StlvX-kOg&feature=related

and then go to Gnome-tweak-settings >themes and change everything to xp

Last step Change your wallpaper.

---

That's only for someone who needs a windows xp similar Desktop session

This isn't end yet , I still needed the convert to the Windows 95 theme.
[image]
IceWM will be great but again , The fonts always seems too small when I get to that session.

Answer (score 0):

There is a complete transformation project: [Chicago95](https://github.com/grassmunk/Chicago95) - it makes all visual style of GNU/Linux look like Windows95.

Also there is [Q4OS](https://q4os.org/) - Linux distribution based on Debian/Ubuntu with themes in various Windows styles (including 2000 and XP). It includes package manager that looks like install-shield for Windows.

If you wish to transform any Linux distro for looking and feeling as Windows 95/98 than you may need to install the GTK environment such as Gnome (default in Ubuntu), Mate (default in Ubuntu-Mate and Linux Mint) or Xfce4 (default in Xubuntu). The last one is the best for Chicago95.

You may use [Redmond97](https://www.pling.com/p/1313764) GTK theme for Gnome or Mate to get 98/2000's style for window decorations and [SE98](https://www.pling.com/p/1581320/) for 98/2000's style icons.

The links for screenshots:

Redmond97 gtk theme
[Redmond97 gtk theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpbS1.png)

Chicago95 full-style theme
[Chicago95 full-style theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CB4Z.png)

SE98 icon theme
[SE98 icon theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8CP6.png)